# What statistical technique could I use to see if gender effect exists in this scenario?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, exploratory-data-analysis

Suppose I give 6 short stories (of word length varying from 200 to 400),and ask N=100 students about which one (e.g., story #1, #2,..., #6) is their favorite story (see below table). **Some data are missing (meaning students didn't like any of the stories)** and I know the gender of the students.

[image]

I think the following questions can be asked about the data (and are easy to calculate):

1. What is the most favorite story among all students? What is the most favorite story among male students? What is the most favorite story among female students?

But let's suppose story #3 is the most favorite among male students and 20 of them voted it as their favorite; on the other hand, story #4 is the most favorite among female students and 24 has voted for it (remember, some students didn't pick their favorite, so some data are missing). I've drawn up a hypothetical data table of this result below.

[image]

Other than reporting the count of these votes and stating that there's a huge difference/divide between male's favorite and female favorite, **which statistical technique could I use to probe into find out if there's a significant difference between male and female favorite picks?**

Please assume that I'm a beginner who's trying to learn statistics and sorry if the questions I asked are very naive. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please consult our [help] for information on what is on-topic here. In particular, we are a *question-and-answer* site, not a "what is my question?" site! If you have some interest in these data then surely you will be able to formulate a question about them of interest to you.

Comment: @whuber Good point. I've edited my question. In fact, "what's my question" is not my motive for this post. I wanted to find out what statistical technique could be used to figure out (prove) if there's a huge difference between male vs. female vote. If you have an suggestion, please feel free to provide an answer. Thanks.